# What service(s) can I use to get Book information from ISBN in C#?

Tags: library, c#, api, amazon

I am building a very simple application in C#. It involves scanning an ISBN on a book with a barcode scanner that simply inputs a string of numbers into the program.

There are a few options that I have come across, but they look as if they can only be implemented via HTML and PHP.

Does anyone have any recommendations for any APIs or Libraries that I can use easily within a C# application to get information about a book via ISBN?

## At minimum, I will need:

> Book Title 
>  Book Author

Code samples and links are welcome. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667361/how-to-retrieve-books-information-in-xml-json-from-library-of-congress-by-isbn and consider parsing some json.

Comment: @SteveBarnes I am fairly new to C# and have never done anything with json or XML.  Are you able to guide me in the correct direction to know how to handle this in C#?

Comment: I use python for that sort of thing - not done much C# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx may be of help.

Comment: How about the [search.books method in Goodreads API](https://www.goodreads.com/api/index#search.books). It, however, requires that you have a developer account

Comment: @SteveBarnes Thanks for the link...I think I have it figured out now! Timmy thanks :)

Comment: Search for BMC on GitHub. It's in Python, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this library [Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising) and install it easy with nuget. The library also supports .NET Standard 2.0.

If you want to use it you have to register with the [amazon affiliate program](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com). This causes no costs. You need an accesskey and the secretkey to start.

Install the library in your project

```
PM> Install-Package Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising
```

Short example for search a book with the isbn:

```
var authentication = new AmazonAuthentication();
authentication.AccessKey = "accesskey";
authentication.SecretKey = "secretkey";

var wrapper = new AmazonWrapper(authentication, AmazonEndpoint.US);
//The Lord of the Rings
var result = wrapper.Lookup("978-0261102385");
```